# google visualisation table changing cell value based on numerical value

Tags: jquery, css, google-visualization

I have a google visualisation table and I want to do two things.

One if format the cell based on the if the cell is a positive or negative number. Second is on the last row of the table draw a border above it, or make the current border thicker.

For the positive and negative values I found a solution but not quite as I want. In my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/519020/) I have used the google example for the colorformat.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
formatter.addRange(null, 0, 'white', 'orange');
formatter.addRange(0, null, 'red', '#33ff33');
formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
formatter.format(data, 2); // Apply formatter to third column
formatter.format(data, 3); // Apply formatter to fourth column
```

This is nearly want I want however I would like the text to be centered and the font in bold, not sure this can be done using the formatter?

So in my fiddle you will also see another attempt using css which is commented out. Below is an example of one row. However when I run this the table shows me [object Object] in every cell, not sure why?

```
data.setCell(0,0,'France', {'className': 'left-text'});
data.setCell(0,1, 325, {'className': 'positive-value'});
data.setCell(0,2, 450, {'className': 'positive-value'});
data.setCell(0,3, 700, {'className': 'positive-value'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) as for the formatter, you are correct, it will only change the color

---

2) as for setting the class name on each cell, your call to `setCell` is missing one argument

`setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, value, formattedValue, properties)`

you're passing an object to the `formattedValue` argument, which should be a string

in order to set the `properties` argument, you'll also need to add the `formattedValue` argument...

```
data.setCell(0,0,'France','France', {'className': 'left-text'});
data.setCell(0,1, 325, '325', {'className': 'positive-value'});
data.setCell(0,2, 450, '450', {'className': 'positive-value'});
data.setCell(0,3, 700, '700', {'className': 'positive-value'});
```

you could also do the following...

```
data.addRow([{v: 'France', p: {'className': 'left-text'}}, {v: 325, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}, {v: 450, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}, {v: 700, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}]);
```

---

3) see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  DrawPerfContrTable();
});

// portfolio contribution figures
function DrawPerfContrTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var options = {
    title: 'PnL',
    showRowNumber: false,
    width: '50%',
    height: '75%',
    allowHtml: true
  };

  data.addColumn('string', '');
  data.addColumn('number', 'MTD');
  data.addColumn('number', 'QTD');
  data.addColumn('number', 'YTD');
  data.addRows(1);

  data.setCell(0,0,'France','France', {'className': 'left-text'});
  data.setCell(0,1, 325, '325', {'className': 'positive-value'});
  data.setCell(0,2, 450, '450', {'className': 'positive-value'});
  data.setCell(0,3, 700, '700', {'className': 'positive-value'});

  data.addRow([{v: 'France', p: {'className': 'left-text'}}, {v: 325, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}, {v: 450, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}, {v: 700, p: {'className': 'positive-value'}}]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tblExample'));
  table.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.right-text {
    text-align: right;
  }

.left-text {
    text-align: left;
  }

.positive-value {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
.negative-value {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="tblExample">

</div>
```

Comment: sorry one quick question, when you use setCell are you able to set the background colour of the cell? I can colour the font and specify the text to be centred but it seems to ignore filling the background colour? I use .green-background {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }  as my class

Comment: could be clashing with the table's default styles -- either add `!important` to your css class --> `.green-background { background-color: lightgreen !important; }` -- or combine `'className'` with `'style'` --> `data.setCell(0,3, 700, '700', {'className': 'positive-value', 'style': 'background-color: lightgreen'});`